# winrt::init_apartment and COM STA initialization

Tags: windows, winapi, com, c++-winrt

Working on a win32 desktop application that uses WinRT APIs. The app also calls COM APIs i.e. com client. As per C++/WinRT documentation, I am supposed to call *winrt::init_apartment*, which by default uses multi-threaded apartment model and also [initializes COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/get-started#:%7E:text=The%20call%20also%20initializes%20COM)

Since my app calls regular COM servers, so I have to use *winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::single_threaded)* call. As per documentation above, it should initialize COM in STA mode as well.

Are there any potential side-effects of initializing WinRT in single threaded mode or conversely, with COM, when app only calls *init_apartment* and not *CoInitialize*?

Comment: The "initialize COM" promise does mean that it calls [CoInitializeEx for you](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/6162c9d05d42281114e0891b7b71f57ea2b6ab5f/strings/base_activation.h#L477).  It is a *promise*, cross your heart hope to die, by selecting STA you assert that the thread follows the STA contract.  It can't block and must have a dispatcher loop.  Failure to implement that contract causes deadlock.

Comment: @HansPassant If I call WinRT APIs from a std::thread running in the background, does that satisfy STA contract? I'm didn't get dispatcher loop part, is that same as message loop that UI thread has?

Comment: Not sure wat you mean by "regular COM servers". CoInitialize(Ex) must be called to initialize COM when COM is required, you call it only once per thread usually at initialisation (not per code path when you need COM) and you can choose STA or MTA, you can't do both simultaneously in the same thread. Choice is up to you, it's not stricly bound to the servers you call although you can optimize if you know beforehand. For example if you do Shell or UI-bound operation, chances are it's better to use STA to avoid cross apartment calls (proxies).

Comment: *"dispatcher loop part, is that same as message loop that UI thread has?"* - Essentially, yes. You'll need a `GetMessage`/`DispatchMessage` loop in every STA thread. Communication (from other threads) with objects living in an STA is done through message passing. Messages are serialized, which establishes a fundamental property of an STA that promises that objects will never be accessed concurrently from multiple threads. You'll still have to be prepared for reentrancy. Mind you, failure to implement a dispatcher loop will frequently *appear* to work.